# Permission Denial : Starting Intent ( lock task mode / kiosk mode )

Tags: android, android-intent, kiosk-mode

Any one have a suggestion how to solve this error ?
I am trying to run lock task with intent **getLaunchIntentForPackage** but I have no idea why this error is coming and which type of permission it wants to run this task.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.example.videoplayer cmp=com.example.videoplayer/.MainActivity } from ProcessRecord{fd194a9 7523:com.example.lock/u0a190} (pid=7523, uid=10190) with lockTaskMode=true
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2326)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1758)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5407)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:597)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5747)
    at com.example.lock.MainActivity.launchApp(MainActivity.kt:110)
    at com.example.lock.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:62)
    at com.example.lock.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$yGvyKllS4GN5cYzDCcbSf8EdXb0(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.lock.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.wm.SafeActivityOptions.checkPermissions(SafeActivityOptions.java:283)
    at com.android.server.wm.SafeActivityOptions.getOptions(SafeActivityOptions.java:155)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1006)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:670)
    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1223)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running into the same error. The only thing I can hand to you is that it can be solved by using the DevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages as stated on the android site: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode#allowlist_apps

Comment: https://snow.dog/blog/kiosk-mode-android You can find help from this documentation if you use setLockTaskPackages, You have to delete device ownership from others like google. You can set your ownership by factory reset and not giving others admin rights. This documentation can help you with this